# Javascript use results from one AJAX function to make another

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a javascript function which uses AJAX to grab the coordinates from a country name PHP file.

```
$("#innerSelect").on("change", () => {     //Handles changing the country select.
    addCountryBorder($("#innerSelect").val());  /* Calls function that adds country border to map */


    $.ajax({                             
        url: "libs/php/getCoordsFromCountryName.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            countryName: $("#innerSelect").val(),
            
        },
        success: function(result) {

            

            if (result.status.name == "ok") {
                
                map.panTo(new L.LatLng(result["data"][0]["geometry"]["lat"] , result["data"][0]["geometry"]["lng"]))
                
            }
        
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(errorThrown);
        }
            

})
});
```

These seem coordinates (lat and long) can be used to grab the country code from a different API, how can I make another AJAX function something like below to take the lat/long from above and use it to navigate to the right country code?

```
function getCountryCode(countryName) {
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/php/countryCode.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            lat and long
        },
        success: function(result) {
  
       GET THE COUNTRY CODE

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    })
}
```

**I have tried this to no avail**

```
let latitude; 
let longitude;

$("#innerSelect").on("change", () => {     //Handles changing the country select.
    addCountryBorder($("#innerSelect").val());  /* Calls function that adds country border to map */


    $.ajax({                             
        url: "libs/php/getCoordsFromCountryName.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            countryName: $("#innerSelect").val(),
            
        },
        success: function(result) {

            

            if (result.status.name == "ok") {
                
                latitude = (result["data"][0]["geometry"]["lat"])
                longitude = (result["data"][0]["geometry"]["lng"])
                map.panTo(new L.LatLng(result["data"][0]["geometry"]["lat"] , result["data"][0]["geometry"]["lng"]))
                
            }
        
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(errorThrown);
        }
            

})
});


let countryCode; 
function getCountryCode(countryName) {
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/php/countryCode.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
                lat: latitude,
                lng: longitude
            },
            success: function(result) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

                if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                    $('#countryCode').html(result['data'][0]['countryCode']);
                    countryCode = (result['data'][0]['countryCode']);


                }
            
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // your error code
            }
        }); 
    
    }


function countryInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/php/countryInfo.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            country: countryCode,
        },
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.status.name == "ok") {
                coords.push({currencyCode: result.data[0].currencyCode});
                
                let formattedPopulation = result['data'][0]['population'].toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                let formattedArea = Math.round(result['data'][0]['areaInSqKm']).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

                $('#continent').html(result['data'][0]['continentName']);
                $('#capital').html(result['data'][0]['capital']);
                $('#countryName').html(result['data'][0]['countryName']);
                $('#population').html(formattedPopulation);
                $('#currencyCode').html(result['data'][0]['currencyCode']);
                $('#area').html(formattedArea);

                currencyConverter();
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR)
            console.log(textStatus)
            console.log(errorThrown)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks like you'll need to nest the second ajax request in the first request that gets the latitude and longitude.  If you don't want to nest, consider declaring some variables for the data outside of both requests and setting them via the first request.

Comment: @micahlt I've included my attempt in the question but I can't seem to get it work and I am quite new to JavaScript :(

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your first ajax request on a function like this

```
 function fetchApi() {
   return jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'yoururl',
   method: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (result) {
    //return the value from the request
    return result;
   }
  });
 }
```

Now you can call your second request just after the first one and pass the lat and long values to it

```
fetchApi().then((data) => //do something with the data)
```